# How do I run "s3-dist-cp" command inside pyspark shell / pyspark script in EMR 5.x

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, s3distcp

I had some problems in running a s3-dist-cp" command in my pyspark script as I needed some data movement from s3 to hdfs for performance enhancement. so here I am sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

os.system("/usr/bin/s3-dist-cp --src=s3://aiqdatabucket/aiq-inputfiles/de_pulse_ip/latest/ --dest=/de_pulse/  --groupBy='.*(additional).*'  --targetSize=64 --outputCodec=none")
```

Note : - please make sure that you give the full path of s3-dist-cp like (/usr/bin/s3-dist-cp)

also, I think we can use subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a pyspark application, you'll have to stop the spark application first. The `s3-dist-cp` will hang because the pyspark application is blocking.

```
spark.stop()  # spark context
os.system("/usr/bin/s3-dist-cp ...")
```